# Use sklearn's FunctionTransformer with string data?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm using sklearn's FunctionTransformer to preprocess some of my data, which are date strings such as "2015-01-01 11:09:15".

My customized function takes a string as input, but I found out that FunctionTransformer cannot deal with strings as in the source code it didn't implement fit_transform. Therefore, the call got routed to parent class as:

```
     57     def fit(self, X, y=None):
     58         if self.validate:
---> 59             check_array(X, self.accept_sparse)
     60         return self
```

The check_array seems only working with numeric ndarrays. Now of course I can do everything in the pandas domain, but I wonder if there's a better way of dealing with this in sklearn - esp. given that I would possibly use a pipeline in the future?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you not convert the datetime strings to `datetime64` dtype first? e.g. `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` then it will be numeric

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realize the method exists. But I still want to know how to do this properly with FunctionTransformer - say I want to do some additional operations in the customized function.

Comment: Hey, I know it is old, but didn't have privilidge yet to comment :)
Did the below work for you?

Comment: Sorry I went with EdChum's answer and haven't checked since then. I don't have the code and cannot check but I think your answer will also work so I marked it as correct. Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems as if the `validate` parameter is what you are looking for:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html

Here an example, where it may make sense to leave it as a string over converting to float as mentioned in the comment. Let's say you want to add time zone info to your date string:

```
import pandas as pd

def add_TZ(df):
    df['date'] = df['date'].astype(str) + "Z"

data = {  'date' : ["2015-01-01 11:00:00", "2015-01-01 11:15:00", "2015-01-01 11:30:00"],
        'value' : [4., 3., 2.]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

This will fail as you noted due to the check:

```
ft = FunctionTransformer(func=add_TZ)
ft.fit_transform(df)
```

Output:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2015-01-01 11:30:00'
```

This works:

```
ft = FunctionTransformer(func=add_TZ, validate=False)
ft.fit_transform(df)
```

Output:

```
    date                    value
0   2015-01-01 11:00:00Z    4.0
1   2015-01-01 11:15:00Z    3.0
2   2015-01-01 11:30:00Z    2.0
```